# Plotting Categorical by Color

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting a segmentation, and running into an issue where my categorical values are only showing up one color. Any advice?

```
    [![fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Sentiment Score', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Star Review', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('Heinz Segmentation', fontsize = 20)


targets = \['Sugar/ Healthy Positives', 'Sugar/ Healthy Negatives', 'Price/ Value Positives', 'Price/ Value Negatives', 'Purists Positives', 'Purists Negatives'\]
colors = \['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y'\]
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    ax.scatter(df.Compound,df.StarsInt
               , c = color
               , s = 200
              ,alpha = .5)
ax.legend(targets, prop={'size': 14})
ax.grid()][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you have a problem in the legends. You forgot to pass the legend while plotting

```
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    ax.scatter(df.Compound,df.StarsInt, c=color,
               s = 200,alpha = .5,       
               label=target) # <--- pass the label to show in legend
```